# Replacing a for statement with a while statement in a repetition structure in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new here and trying to get help with some work for school. I need to make this code:

```
do    //begin loop
{
     cout << "Year " << years << ":" << endl;

     for (double rate = .02; rate < .05; rate += .01)
     {
          balance = principal * pow(1 + rate, years);
          //Display rate with zero decimal places
          cout << fixed << set precision(0);
          cout << "   Rate " << rate * 100 << "%: $";
          //Display balance with two decimal places
          cout << setprecision(2) << balance << endl;
     }    //End for

     //Update years counter
     years += 1;
}    while (years < 6);
```

Go from being a for statement to a while statement. I'm having some issues and hopefully I can get some insight into how to do this properly. Thank you!

Comment: What's your problem in particular? What did you try?

Comment: Can you explain / show examples of what you've tried? Have a read here about how to ask homework questions and what you should include to ensure you get an answer, and not just downvoted and ignored :) 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You know that a `for` statement has 3 parts? Have you identified them? A `while` statement has only one expression, and you should have learned which of the 3 parts of the `for` loop correspond to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to understand what the for loop does:

```
double rate = 0.2 // initialization
rate < .05 // condition and
rate += .01 // the afterthought.
```

So at first you are setting your rate variable once then you are checking if rate is less than .05 and before the next loop you ingrement rate by .01.

You can do the same thing with the while loop, if you add before the loop:

```
double rate = 0.2
```

and at the end of the loop you add:

```
rate += .01
```